# How do I remove the margin around a collapsed header in ExtJS

Tags: extjs

Is it possible to style a collapsed header in ExtJS so that it doesn't have a margin around it?

It seems it's all being positioned using javascript which means all my attempts to tweak it so far have been futile.

Any help will hopefully prevent me from ramming a full bag of heroin into my veins in order to forget that ExtJS exists for a few precious hours.

Comment: Wow.  Your constant griping about how terrible Ext is really makes me want to spend more time helping you.

Comment: My bad I suppose. This isn't the place to bitch. But.... it does suck, there's no way around that, and it's frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cmargins like you would margins.